# validating textangular text length

Tags: angularjs

Im using the textangular, and I need to limit the length of the text.
I know that this can be sone using ta-max-text.

But I need to display a error if the text excedes the limit. Textangular sets the model to undefined, when the limit is excedded. This leaves me with a problem. When the page is loaded initialy, the model is also undifined.

How can I figure out if the model is undefined due to a fresh page load or because the limit have been excedded?

Can I access the hidden text in any way?

https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just checked ta-max-text directive source. It sets the validation false your textarea like this :

```
ctrl.$setValidity('taMaxText', false);
```

You can use ng-if directive and check for validity property of your textArea to hide or show message.

```
ng-if="yourFormName.$error.taMaxText"
```

Here is the demo [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ktqe8z86ohlKXJSjJwKV?p=preview). You can show alert span if your text length > 10.

Answer (score 2):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/MegBJYkkyh3qsNJhyfNP?p=preview

```
<div ng-model="content" text-angular="" ></div>

<h3 ng-show="content.length > 20">Text tooo long</h3>
```